# How to set a button middle of the screen on android

Tags: android

I am having a little issue with my positioning of my buttons in my android app. Bascially if you look at the image below

I have three buttons. I want the buttons positioned as they are except with the 'Players 2' button displayed smack bang middle of the screen.

I tried setting layout_parentcenter but this had no affect and I don't want to do it by margins because when I tried this the buttons were not in the correct position when I rotated the phone to horizontal.

Below is the image of the current buttons layout:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/brick_wall">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title "
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_players1"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1 Player"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_players2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2 Players"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="How to Play"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change your relative layout orientation with horizontal.

Comment: Make your button_players2 as centerParent=true and then try to adjust other two layouts as <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_players1"
            android:layout_above="@id/button_players2"/> and <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players2">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your button_players2 in center of the vertical and put button_players1 above button_players2. 
 button_players1,button_players2 and button_how_to_play will be in center of the screen.
Try to paste below code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/brick_wall"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Title "
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_players1"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_players2"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1 Player"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_players2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2 Players"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="How to Play"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already using layout_centerHorizontal.  The one for the other direction is layout_centerVertical.  You'll probably want to put all the buttons inside a linear layout and center the layout, rather than centering the buttons (otherwise the 3 will layout on top of one another).

The reason it isn't working for you right now (you do have layout_centerVertical on the bottom 2 buttons) is that you're also imposing layout_below constraints on them, and those are overriding it.  Don't use both-  instead either use a LinearLayout as I suggested or use layout_above on the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title "
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">



            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_players1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1 Player"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_players2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/button_players1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2 Players"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="How to Play"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/footer_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take group of buttons and wrap it in relativelayout and make that relative layout parent center or vertical and horizontal center

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/brick_wall">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title "
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight" />
  <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
       android:layout_centerParent="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_players1"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1 Player"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_players2"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2 Players"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_how_to_play"
        android:layout_width="148dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_players2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
        android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="How to Play"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footer_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```